# How do you access the coordinates in a boost graph topology layout?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I'm trying to create an application which displays a simple graph and since I'm using boost::graph for the underlying data structure, I'd like to use the layouting algorithms available in the library as well.

The answer presented here explains how to use a layout algorithm within the boost library to lay out vertices of graph: 
[How does the attractive force of Fruchterman Reingold work with Boost Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815336/how-does-the-attractive-force-of-fruchterman-reingold-work-with-boost-graph-libr?rq=1)

But sadly it does not explain how - after the layout has been calculated - the coordinates of the vertices can actually be accessed. Even though we get a vector of positions (or rather points), the float components are private, so that doesn't help. The boost::graph documentation also doesn't address this topic.

So how can simple (X,Y) coordinates of each vertex be retrieved after a layouting algorithm has been applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the boost graph source code it turned out that this isn't so hard after all.
We can use a property map to iterate over the PositionsMap and the [] operator to access the coordinates:

```
template<typename Graph, typename Positions>
void print_positions(const Graph &g, const Positions &positions) {
    auto index_map = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, graph);

    using PropertyMap = boost::iterator_property_map<Positions::iterator, decltype(index_map)>;
    PropertyMap position_map(positions.begin(), index_map);
    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, graph, Graph) {
        Position pos = position_map[v];
        cout << v << ": " << pos[0] << "|" << pos[1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, do you have a full example of this code? Because I can not seem to replicate this..

Comment: @sdgawerzswer Sorry, not anymore - Maybe you can ask a new question with your problem and we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I meanwhile wrote a custom wrapper, which uses only the positions: basically a loop where pos[0] and pos[1] are mapped to indiviudal nodes. Thank you anyways.